# How to install php 5 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I tried to use this command to install php in Ubuntu 16.04:

> sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5

But it shows:

> 'php5' has no installation candidate

How can I install it?

Comment: to run just `$ php /find/location/file` to install on ubuntu 6 i think php 7 will installed

Comment: maybe u wanna read  this `https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu`

Comment: your provided link is not reach 404 error

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 comes with PHP 7.0. If you want to install version 5, you'll have to find a third party source or compile from source.

Comment: You might get better help at [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/). There are already posts there related to this topic, like this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/756879/cant-install-php5-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 9):

Ubuntu 16.04 comes with PHP7, so there are no PHP5 packages.

However, if you like, you can add a PPA to get those packages:

Remove all the stock php packages

List installed php packages with dpkg -l | grep php| awk '{print $2}' |tr "\n" " " then remove unneeded packages with sudo aptitude purge your_packages_here or if you want to directly remove them all use :

```
sudo aptitude purge `dpkg -l | grep php| awk '{print $2}' |tr "\n" " "`
```

Add the PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

Install your PHP Version

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5.6
```

You can install php5.6 packages.

Then, verify your PHP version

```
sudo php -v
```